# Custom font bold weight not working in Dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using [Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) to generate and send a PDF via email from my Wordpress site. I am attempting to use a custom font and the `normal` font-weight is working correctly, but `bold` is not.

Here's what my HTML variable looks like:

```
$html =
'<html>
  <body>
    <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Proxima Nova";
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      src: url(' . get_template_directory() . '/fonts/ProximaNova-Reg.woff2) format("woff2"), url(' . get_template_directory() . '/fonts/ProximaNova-Reg.woff) format("woff");
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Proxima Nova";
      font-weight: bold;
      font-style: normal;
      src: url(' . get_template_directory() . '/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.woff2) format("woff2"), url(' . get_template_directory() . '/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.woff) format("woff");
    }
    body,html {font-family:"Proxima Nova";}
    </style>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>';
```

When I open the generated PDF, the `td`s are correctly displayed in the Proxima Nova font, but the `th`s are not. The weird thing is that if I just email the HTML to myself using `wp_mail` the bold font works correctly. It's only in the PDF that it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Screenshot from the email:
[image]

Screenshot from the PDF:
[image]

I do not have the font installed locally

Comment: Try setting an explicit style of `th{font-weight: bold;}` to see if that kicks it in.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue, at one point I was using the `TrueType` version of the `normal` font weight but not the `bold`. Apparently `php-font-lib` can only generate the compatible fonts from a `ttf` file and not `woff`. When I switched both declarations over to `ttf` it generated the necessary files and now both weights are working.